# How to Convert "struct tm" (VTYPE_TM) to DATE(double) - Native API?

Tags: c++

I am writing a small DLL in native C++ (Visual Studio 2013 version) using *Native API* technology.

From an external program inside my DLL, I get the Date (no Time: only day, month, year) as a variable of type **VTYPE_TM** (this is ***"struct tm"***).

```
if (paParams[0].vt == VTYPE_TM) 
 double dateFrom = (double)paParams[0].tmVal ; // convert error - but how ?
```

Next, I need to convert this date, which is contained inside the **tm** structure, to the **DATE(double)** type.

More information about **DATE(double)** can be found here - in the online calculator https://planetcalc.com/7027/.

**Now the actual question and my problem:** how do I convert *"struct tm"* to *DATE(double)* ?

As I understand it, we need to write a function that will convert each field value from the tm structure to the required double. But isn't there a ready-made solution? Perhaps I need to use some intermediate type, but I don't know which one.

Can you please tell me how to implement this?

A question for the hardcore C ++ programming gurus!

Comment: What is it this `DATE(double)`? What units? What is value of EPOC time? Can you provide link to documentation? Best approach use some ready solution, for example `Boost.Date_Time` or https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: DATE(double) is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/82ab7w69(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done with C++20 `<chrono>`.  Unfortunately this part of C++20 isn't shipping yet, but vendors are busy implementing it.

Fortunately there exists a [free, open-source, header-only preview of this part of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which works with C++11/14/17.  Additionally, the preview has an [examples page with this very problem already worked](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#TDate) out as an example.

Here is the example translated to just convert back and forth with type `double`, including all of the test cases from the [documentation page you link to](https://planetcalc.com/7027/).

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

template <class D>
date::sys_time<D>
to_sys_time(double dt)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using fdays = duration<double, days::period>;
    using ftime = time_point<system_clock, fdays>;
    auto ft = ftime{fdays{dt}};
    if (ft < ftime{})
    {
        auto d = time_point_cast<days>(ft);
        auto t = d - ft;
        ft = d + t;
    }
    ft -= sys_days{1970_y/January/1} - sys_days{1899_y/December/30};
    return round<D>(ft);
}

template <class D>
double
to_double(date::sys_time<D> tp)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using fdays = duration<double, days::period>;
    using ftime = time_point<system_clock, fdays>;
    auto ft = ftime{tp} + (sys_days{1970_y/January/1} - sys_days{1899_y/December/30});
    if (ft >= ftime{})
        return ft.time_since_epoch().count();
    auto d = floor<days>(ft);
    auto t = d - ft;
    return (d + t).time_since_epoch().count();
}

void
test(double d)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;

    auto t = to_sys_time<seconds>(d);
    auto d2 = to_double(t);
    cout << d << " is " << t << " which is " << d2 << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    test(-1.25);
    test(-1.3);
    test(-0.5);
    test(0.5);

    year_month_day today = floor<days>(system_clock::now());

    std::tm tm{};
    tm.tm_year = int{today.year()} - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = unsigned{today.month()} - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = unsigned{today.day()};

    sys_days sd = year{tm.tm_year + 1900}/(tm.tm_mon + 1)/tm.tm_mday;
    cout << "Today " << today << " is " << to_double(sd) << '\n';
}
```

This currently outputs:

```
-1.25 is 1899-12-29 06:00:00 which is -1.25
-1.3 is 1899-12-29 07:12:00 which is -1.3
-0.5 is 1899-12-30 12:00:00 which is 0.5
0.5 is 1899-12-30 12:00:00 which is 0.5
Today 2021-01-30 is 44226
```

The first four lines simply confirm that the conversion functions result in the correct values according to your documentation.

Finally the current date (UTC) is obtained from `system_clock::now()`, converted to a `std::tm`, and then converted back to a days-precision `chrono::time_point` (based on `system_clock`).  This `time_point` is then fed into `to_double` to convert it to a double, which currently results in 44226.

These conversion functions are needlessly complicated to take into account the bizarre history of this format described in the last paragraph of [your documentation](https://planetcalc.com/7027/).

Comment: As I said - I dont use C++ 20. I use Native C++ 98 which comes with VS 2013.

Comment: What is the date.h header file? Where can I download it? Are its features supported by C ++ 98?

Comment: Maybe,I need to update my Visual Studio from 2013 to (what version?) to support C++ 11 and your date.h lib..

Comment: You will need, at a minimum, C++11 to use this.  It is based on the std header `<chrono>`.  If you don't have `<chrono>`, abandon any plans to use this.  I don't know what version of VS first supports `<chrono>`, but I'm sure you can search for that.  date.h is at the first link in my answer.

Comment: I'd setup VS 2019 16.8.1  Enterprise and trying to add "date.h". But after Rebuild solution the error appears: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2059 syntax error: '('my_project\include\date\date.h 419 
This is screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/AL9WvGB

Comment: `#define NOMINMAX` prior to including any Windows header.

Comment: Thank you very much! All works fine! You are best C++ guru!